# Can I post an JS array to php via ajax, if button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass `valuesArray` to php if `button` is clicked, when `anotherButton` is clicked, i want to print this array in PHP.

**home.js:**

```
button.onclick = function (){

    valuesArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']

$.post('index.php', {data: valuesArray});
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
    If(isset($_POST['anotherButton'])){
        $getData = $_POST['data'];
        print_r($getData);
    } 
?>
```

If button gets clicked I get

> undefined index: data

which should mean that `data` wasn't passed to PHP.

Comment: Try to use different index name (not data)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('index.php', {"data": valuesArray},function(return,result){});
```

Notice the double quote around "data".
Also may need to json encode valuesArray?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('index.php', valuesArray, function(result) {
    // ....
});
```

Have a look at documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/